# how to change the user agent in the pytube module in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, user-agent, pytube

I am trying to download youtube videos using the pytube module but everytime i run it i get this error:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

This is for a web app i am trying to make

Code:

```
from pytube import Youtube

print("What would you like to download ?")
print(f"1/Youtube Video, 2/Image, 3/Song")
userinput = int(input())

if userinput == 1:
    n()


def n():
    print("insert url:")
    u = input()
    download_videos(u)


def download_videos(link):
    yt = YouTube(link)
    yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by(
        'resolution').desc().first().download()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but fixed it by changing a file in PyDub.
the file was for me located here:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pytube\innertube.py
```

here you need to make a change on **line 223**.
Replace `client='ANDROID_MOBILE'` with `client='ANDROID'`

[the file is called innertube.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGJAr.png)

[Change client from Android to WEB (old photo but you get the idea)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni4D6.png)